# Contagem de ID com o Firebase - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, id

Na minha aplicação, eu tenho uma entidade chamada **Game** que possui, entre outros atributos, um **ID**. Eu preciso que cada vez que essa entidade for instanciada o ID seja incrementado + 1. Isso funciona até que aplicação seja encerrada, pois quando abro a app novamente a contagem do ID é reiniciada, dessa forma quando eu crio um novo **Game** e submeto para o Firebase, ele sobrescreve o elemento que já existia com aquele **ID** ao invés de criar um novo. Preciso salvar de alguma forma essa contagem de **IDs**, ou então recuperar o tamanho da lista de **Games** já cadastradas no Firebase, para que quando a aplicação for iniciada novamente o **ID** continue contando de onde parou. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? E como fazer?

Aqui está como eu estou fazendo para contar o **ID** na Entidade **Game**:

```
public class Game {

   private static int cont = 1;
   private int id;
   ...

   //Construtor
   public Game() {
    this.id = cont++;
   }
}
```

E aqui é onde eu estou submetendo o novo **Game** para o Firebase na RegisterGamesActivity2:

```
private boolean registerGame(Game game){
    try{
        firebase = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Game");
        firebase.child(String.valueOf(game.getId())).setValue(game);
        Toast.makeText(RegisterGamesActivity2.this, "Jogo cadastrado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caique por que você não faz o seguinte cria uma variável no firabase contadorID que quando criar o game você vai la e seta esta variável, e nas próximas mudanças você pode usar .Onchange do firebase para mudar este valor.

Agora se você quer fazer isto para cada usuário recomendo você colocar este ID dentro do cadastro do usuário e cada jogo que ele começa você muda o valor lá.